# need advice regarding design and performance issue

Tags: java, android, class, object

I have data retrieved from a server at very high rate, the datas sent are in form of a message that resembles the following format:

```
$FMSn,par1,par2...,...,...,...,..,...,....,par20 //where n is number ranges from 1 to 12
```

this message I need to process to parse some data.

but less frequently the server sends other message in different format, that message is not important and could be discarded and the difference between it and the previously described messages in format is that
the previous message starts with $FMS while the other message not.

to distinguish between these messages to know which one is that should be processed, i created a class FMSParser as shown below and i checked if the message header is

```
$FMS
```

or not.

my question is, should i create a new object of FMSParser class in the loop in which the messages from the server are received or create one object in the whole 
program and in the loop in which the data are recived i just call isValid method and getParam(). in other words in code:

should i choose solution 1 or 2?

**solution 1**:

```
 loop for messages receiving:

    msg = receive message();
    fmsParser = new FMSParser(msg);

    if (fmsParser.isValid) {
        params = fmsParser.getParam();
    }
```

**solution 2**:

```
 fmsParser = new FMSParser();
 loop for messages receiving:

    msg = receive message();

    if (fmsParser.isValid(msg)) {
        params = fmsParser.getParam();
    }
```

**code**:

```
private class FMSParser {

private final static String HEADER = "$FMS"
private String[] mSplittedMsg;

    FMSParser() {}

    public boolean isValidMsg(String msg) {
        boolean isValid = false;

        this.mSplittedMsg = msg.split(",");

        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {

            if (splittedMsg[0].equals(HEADER+i)) {
                valid = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        return valid;
    }

    public String [] getParam() {
        return this.mSplittedMsg;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you construct a new FMSParser each time through the loop, it will require memory allocation and garbage collection.

I would choose option 3 which makes the FMSParser immutable, meaning it is thread-safe.

```
FMSParser fmsParser = new FMSParser();
while (messageIterator.hasNext()) {
   String msg = messageIterator.next();
   if (fmsParser.isValid(msg)) {
       params = fmsParser.getParam(msg);
   }
}
```

Eg:

```
public class FMSParser {
    public boolean isValid(String msg) {
       return msg.startsWith("$FMS");
    }

    public String[] getParams(String msg) {
       return msg.split(",");
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for answer ...but i think it is the same as option 2

Comment: No, it's not. There's one significant difference, my option 3 passes the message string into both `isValid(msg)` and `getParam(msg)`. This means that the FMSParser can be immutable / stateless

Comment: You option 2 assumes that isValid() will always be called before getParam()

Comment: please bear with me, i could not realise any difference between your code posted in the first snipet and my solution2 posted above...the only difference i realised is the getParams method..in my solution it is without any argument sent to it and in you answer it receives msg as argument

Comment: yes... and this very significant difference means that my solution can be stateless. Whilst in your solution you hold mutable state in the FMSParser between isValid() and getparam(). This means that it's not threadsafe.